# Log all messages ever sent in a specific channel discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was wondering if there was a way to log every single message ever sent in one specific discord server and log them to a txt file. I have this code so far, but I think it only logs new messages being sent. I need it to log all.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  await bot.process_commands(message)
  if (message.channel.id == '655864692333477926'):
  sentmsg2 = str(message.content)
  f=open("speclog.txt", "a+")
  for i in range(1):
   f.write(sentmsg2 + "\r\n")
```

Comment: message.channel.id == '655864692333477926' `channel.id` is an integer, not a string. And https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history to answer your question

Comment: where on the doc?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a for loop in your code that reads the message history. Here's how.

```
counter = 0
async for message in channel.history(limit=LIMIT_HERE):
    if message.author == client.user:
        counter += 1
        # Write the 'message' variable in to the file
```

You can find more information here. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history

Comment: So I now have this:
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  await bot.process_commands(message)
  if message.channel.id == '754386245429362778':
    counter = 0
    async for message in message.channel.history(limit=100):
      if message.author == bot.user:
        counter += 1    
        f=open("speclog.txt", "a+")
  for i in range(1):
    f.write(counter + "\r\n")

there are no errors, but its not logging anything

Comment: @haloper maybe delete for i in range

Comment: @haloper try change a+ to w